# jquery address picker that will get latitude and longitude using codeingiter

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps

Hi i have this address that will pick up the latitude and longitude of the textbox filed. The textbox field is the address. Once the user will input the address then save it wil also picks up the lattitude and longitude. Im using it on codeiniter. Does anyone here know where will i able to find it?. I search on google but nothing comforts me at all. Any help is muchly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can user [Google Maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) that will give you lat long according to the address given.

Comment: do you have samples on it?

Comment: Example is given in maps api. You just need to create api access key, make ajax call and parse the response JSON.